# Is it possible to get the trace value of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I want to find a general formula for the trace of the following $N\times N$ matrix raised to the power of $d$, where $d \in \mathbb{N}$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 N-2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & N-3 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & N-3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & N-3 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & N-2     
 \end{bmatrix}^d
$$

For example when $N=4$ and $d=2$, it will look like this
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\   
 \end{bmatrix}^2
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 5 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
 3 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\   
 \end{bmatrix},
$$
so the value of trace for $N=4$ and $d=2$ is $5+3+3+5=16$.

So far I found the solutions for $N=2$ and $N=3$ and $N=4$, but I can't find any patterns from it.
$$
N=2 : a_d=(-1)^d+1
$$
$$
N=3 : a_d=2^d+(-1)^d+1
$$
$$
N=4 : a_d=3^d+(1+\sqrt2)^d+(1-\sqrt2)^d+1
$$

Comment: Is d an arbitrary value?

Comment: What is a “generalized trace”?

Comment: @lukek What does the $d$ superscript mean, and why does it not appear in the formulas for $N = 2,3,4$? Also, what is the $n$ in $a_n$? Should that be $a_N$?

Comment: @lukek Please do not [post the same question multiple times](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4633576/81360). I recommend that you delete the earlier version

Comment: @lukek Should $n$ be $d$ instead?

Comment: @lukek This matrix is related to the [discretized second derivative operator with Neumann boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative#Neumann_case); the eigenvalues of the matrix can be found using this fact. How exactly we should use these eigenvalues depends on what you're actually asking. Unfortunately, as the comments on your question demonstrate, it's not clear what you're asking

Comment: What I wanted to ask is that if it is possible to get the trace value ($\sum m_{i,i}$) when random integer $N, d$ is given

Comment: I fixed the things you guys wrote on the comments.

Comment: @BenGrossmann So is it possible to generalize the trace value for all $N$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{
-1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -2 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -2 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -1  
}
$$
corresponds to the [discretized second derivative operator with Neumann boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative#Neumann_case) (with $h=1$). As the linked page indicates, its eigenvalues are given by
$$
\lambda_j = -4 \sin^2\left(\frac {\pi j}{2N} \right), \quad j = 0,1,\dots,N-1.
$$
The matrix that you are considering is given by $M = A + (N-1)I$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. It follows that the eigenvalues of $n$ are given by $N - 1 + \lambda_j$ (with $\lambda_j$ as above), and the trace of $M^d$ is given by
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(M^d) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (N - 1 + \lambda_j)^d = 
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \left(N - 1 - 4\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi j}{2 N} \right)\right)^d.
$$
We can rewrite this by noting that
$$
\sin^2 \left(\frac{\pi j}{2N} \right) = \frac 12 \left[1 - \cos\left( \frac{\pi j}{N}\right) \right] \implies\\
N - 1 - 4\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi j}{2 N}\right) = 
N - 1 - \left[2 - 2\cos\left(\frac{\pi j}{N}\right)\right] = 
N - 3 + 2 \cos\left( \frac{\pi j}{N}\right).
$$

---

For the case of $N = 4$, this gives us
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(M^d) = \\
\left(1 + 2\cos(0)\right)^d + 
\left(1 + 2\cos(\pi/4)\right)^d + 
\left(1 + 2\cos(\pi/2)\right)^d +
\left(1 + 2\cos(3 \pi /4)\right)^d = \\
3^d + (1 + \sqrt{2})^d + 1^d + (1 - \sqrt{2})^d,
$$
confirming your result. We could obtain a similar closed form for $N = 5$ by noting that
$$
\cos(\pi/5) = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}, \quad 
\cos(2\pi/5) = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}, \\
\cos(3 \pi /5) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4},\quad 
\cos(4 \pi /5) = \frac{-1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}.
$$

---

Here is an attempt to rewrite the sum. For convenience, take $p = N-3$. We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}(p + 2 \cos(\pi j/N))^d &= 
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \sum_{k=0}^d \binom dk 2^k p^{d-k}\cos^k(\pi j/N) 
\\ & = 
\sum_{k=0}^d \binom dk 2^k p^{d-k} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\cos^k(\pi j/N)
\end{align}

I suspect that there is a relatively quick way to compute $\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\cos^k(\pi j/N)$. In particular, write
$\cos(\pi j/N) = \frac 12 (\omega^j + \omega^{-j})$, where $\omega = \exp(\pi i/N)$. From there, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\cos^k(\pi j/N) &= 
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} 2^{-k}(\omega^{j} + \omega^{-j})^k
\\ & = 
2^{-k} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \sum_{\ell = 0}^k \binom k{\ell}\omega^{(k - 2\ell)j}
\\ & = 
2^{-k}  \sum_{\ell = 0}^k \binom{k}{\ell} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\omega^{(k - 2\ell)j}
\\ & = 
2^{-k}   \sum_{\ell = 0}^k \binom{k}{\ell}
\cdot \begin{cases}
\frac {1 - \omega^{(k - 2\ell)N}}{1 - \omega^{(k - 2\ell)}} & 2\ell \neq k\\
N & 2\ell = k
\end{cases}
\\ & = 
2^{-k}   \sum_{\ell = 0}^k \binom{k}{\ell}
\cdot \begin{cases}
\frac {1 - (-1)^{(k - 2\ell)}}{1 - \omega^{(k - 2\ell)}} & 2\ell \neq k\\
N & 2\ell = k
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
From there, there are two cases to consider. If $k$ is odd, then $k - 2\ell$ is odd for all $\ell$, which means that the above sum becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\cos^k(\pi j/N) &= 
2^{-k}   \sum_{\ell = 0}^k \binom{k}{\ell} \frac {1 - (-1)}{1 - \omega^{k - 2\ell}}
\\ & = 
2^{-k} \sum_{\ell = 0}^k \binom{k}{\ell} \frac 2{1 - \omega^{k - 2\ell}}.
\end{align}
Grouping the $\ell = m$ terms with the $\ell = k + 1 - m$ terms in the above some yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\cos^k(\pi j/N) &= 
2^{-k} \sum_{m = 0}^{(k-1)/2} \binom{k}{m} \left[\frac 2{1 - \omega^{k - 2m}} + \frac 2{1 - \omega^{-(k - 2m)}}\right]
\\ & = 
2^{-k} \sum_{m = 0}^{(k-1)/2} \binom{k}{m} 4\operatorname{Re}\left[\frac 1{1 - \omega^{k - 2m}}\right]
\\ & = 
2^{-k} \sum_{m = 0}^{(k-1)/2} \binom{k}{m} 4\operatorname{Re}\left[\frac {1 - \omega^{-(k - 2m)}}{|1 - \omega^{k - 2m}|^2}\right]
\\ & = 
2^{-k} \sum_{m = 0}^{(k-1)/2} \binom{k}{m} 4\operatorname{Re}\left[\frac {(1 - \cos((k - 2m)\pi/N)) + i\sin((k - 2m)\pi/N)
}{(1 - \cos((k - 2m)\pi/N))^2 + \sin^2((k - 2m)\pi/N)}\right]
\\ & = 
2^{-k} \sum_{m = 0}^{(k-1)/2} \binom{k}{m} 4
\frac{1 - \cos((k - 2m)\pi/N)}{2(1 - \cos((k - 2m)\pi/N))}
\\ & = 
2^{-k} \sum_{m = 0}^{(k-1)/2} 2\binom{k}{m}
\\ & = 
2^{-k} \sum_{m = 0}^{k} \binom{k}{m} = 1
\end{align}

If $k$ is even, then the numerator $1 - (-1)^{k - 2\ell}$ will be zero for all $\ell \neq k/2$, which means that the sum becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\cos^k(\pi j/N) &= 
2^{-k}  \binom{k}{k/2} N.
\end{align}
That is, we have
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\cos^k(\pi j/N) = \phi(k) := 
\begin{cases}
2^{-k}  \binom{k}{k/2} N & k \text{ is even}\\
1  & k \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Putting that together with the earlier work, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}(p + 2 \cos(\pi j/N))^d &= 
\sum_{k=0}^d \binom dk 2^k p^{d-k} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\cos^k(\pi j/N)
\\ & = \sum_{k=0}^d \binom dk 2^k p^{d-k} \phi(k)
\\ & = N\left[\sum_{k \leq d, \ k \text{ even}}\binom dk \binom{k}{k/2} p^{d-k}\right]
 + \sum_{k \leq d, \ k \text{ odd}} \binom dk 2^k p^{d-k}
\end{align}
The second summation could be simplified a bit further still:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k \leq d, \ k \text{ odd}} \binom dk 2^k p^{d-k} &=
\frac 12 \sum_{k = 0}^d \binom dk 2^k(1 - (-1)^k) p^{d-k}
\\ & = 
\frac 12 \sum_{k = 0}^d \binom dk 2^k p^{d-k}
- \frac 12 \sum_{k = 0}^d \binom dk (-2)^k p^{d-k}
\\ & =
\frac{(p+2)^d - (p-2)^d}{2}.
\end{align}

---

The final formula, including corrections described below:

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}(p + 2 \cos(\pi j/N))^d &= 
N\left[\sum_{k \leq d, \ k \text{ even}}\binom dk p^{d-k}\sum_{m = -\lfloor k/(2N)\rfloor}^{\lfloor k/(2N)\rfloor}
\binom{k}{\frac k2 - Nm}\right]
 \\ & \qquad + \frac{(p+2)^d - (p-2)^d}{2}
\end{align}

---

Here's a quick Python script that verifies that the (final, corrected) formula works.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power as m_p
from math import comb

N = 7
p = N - 3

A = (N-3)*np.eye(N, dtype = int)
A[[0,-1],[0,-1]] += 1
A += np.diag(np.ones(N-1), k=1).astype(int)
A += np.diag(np.ones(N-1), k=-1).astype(int)

for d in range(10,21):
    ans = ((p+2)**d - (p-2)**d)//2
    ans += sum(N * comb(d,k) * p**(d-k) 
               * sum(comb(k, k//2 - N*m) 
                for m in range(-k//(2*N),1 + k//(2*N)))
               for k in range(0,d+1,2))
    
    print(f"Via formula: {ans}")
    print(f"Direct comp: {np.trace(m_p(A,d))}")
    print()
```

---

The work for $\phi(k)$ for the case where $k$ is even is wrong. We instead have
\begin{align}
\phi(k) & = 2^{-k}   \sum_{\ell = 0}^k \binom{k}{\ell}
\cdot \begin{cases}
\frac {1 - (-1)^{(k - 2\ell)}}{1 - \omega^{(k - 2\ell)}} & 2N \nmid (k - 2\ell)\\
N & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Note that $k - 2\ell = 2Nm$ (for some integer $m$) implies that $\ell = \frac k2 - Nm$. With that, we have
\begin{align}
\phi(k) & = 2^{-k}   \sum_{\ell = 0}^k \binom{k}{\ell}
\cdot \begin{cases}
\frac {1 - (-1)^{(k - 2\ell)}}{1 - \omega^{(k - 2\ell)}} & 2N \nmid (k - 2\ell)\\
N & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\ & = 
2^{-k} N\sum_{m = -\lfloor k/(2N)\rfloor}^{\lfloor k/(2N)\rfloor}
\binom{k}{\frac k2 - Nm}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I can't put the full source code in the comments so I'll just put it here.

I calculated the value in two different ways: one with your formula, and one by just calculating everything.

If you run this code, you'll see that there's difference in $d>=2N$ by varying the $N$ value.

```
P = 998244353

def matrix_mult(A, B, N):
    temp = [[0] * N for _ in range(N)]
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(N):
                temp[i][j] += (A[i][k] * B[k][j]) % P
    return temp

def Mtrace(N, d):
    A =[[0 for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(N)]

    for i in range(1, N):
        A[i][i] = N-3
        A[i-1][i] = 1
        A[i][i-1] = 1

    A[0][0] = N-2
    A[N-1][N-1] = N-2

    C = [[0 for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(N)]
    for i in range(N):
        C[i][i] = 1

    l = [N]
    for i in range(d):
        sum = 0
        C = matrix_mult(A, C, N)
        for i in range(N): 
            sum += C[i][i]
        l.append(sum%P)

    return l


def comb(n, k):
    k = min(k, n - k)
    if k == 0:
        return 1

    top = 1
    bot = 1

    for i in range(k):
        top = top * (n - i) % P
        bot = bot * (i + 1) % P

    inv = pow(bot, P-2, P)

    return top * inv % P

def trace(N,d):
    if N==2:
        return 0 if d&1 else 2

    s1 = 0
    for i in range(0, d+1, 2):
        s1 += comb(d,i)*comb(i,i//2)*pow(N-3, d-i)
        s1 %= P

    s1 = (s1 * N) % P

    s2 = pow(N-1, d, P) - pow(N-5, d, P)
    if s2 % 2 == 1:
        s2 = (s2 + P) // 2
    else:
        s2 //= 2
    
    return (s1+s2)%P


N=20
list = Mtrace(N, 101)
for d in range(1, 100):
    sum = trace(N, d)
    print(f'd={d} | diff : {sum-list[d]} | formula : {sum} | matrix : {list[d]}')
sum = Mtrace(N,d)
```

Here's the new code based on your new edits, and it's perfect!!

````
P = 998244353

def matrix_mult(A, B, N):
    temp = [[0] * N for _ in range(N)]
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(N):
                temp[i][j] += (A[i][k] * B[k][j]) % P
    return temp

def Mtrace(N, d):
    A =[[0 for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(N)]

    for i in range(1, N):
        A[i][i] = N-3
        A[i-1][i] = 1
        A[i][i-1] = 1

    A[0][0] = N-2
    A[N-1][N-1] = N-2

    C = [[0 for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(N)]
    for i in range(N):
        C[i][i] = 1

    l = [N]
    for i in range(d):
        sum = 0
        C = matrix_mult(A, C, N)
        for i in range(N): 
            sum += C[i][i]
        l.append(sum%P)

    return l


def comb(n, k):
    k = min(k, n - k)
    if k == 0:
        return 1

    top = 1
    bot = 1

    for i in range(k):
        top = top * (n - i) % P
        bot = bot * (i + 1) % P

    inv = pow(bot, P-2, P)

    return top * inv % P

def trace(N,d):
    if N==2:
        return 0 if d&1 else 2

    s1 = 0
    for i in range(d//2+1):
        tmp = i//N
        ss1=0
        for j in range(-tmp, tmp+1):
            ss1 += comb(2*i, i-N*j)
        s1 += comb(d,2*i)*ss1*pow(N-3, d-2*i)
        s1 %= P

    s1 = (s1 * N) % P

    s2 = pow(N-1, d, P) - pow(N-5, d, P)
    if s2 % 2 == 1:
        s2 = (s2 + P) // 2
    else:
        s2 //= 2
    
    return (s1+s2)%P


N=20
list = Mtrace(N, 101)
for d in range(1, 100):
    sum = trace(N, d)
    print(f'd={d} | diff : {sum-list[d]} | formula : {sum} | matrix : {list[d]}')
sum = Mtrace(N,d)
```
````

Comment: By the way, what are you using this trace computation for? I'd be interested in hearing about the application

Comment: @BenGrossmann There's this website called baekjoon, it's like korean version of codeforces. I don't know if it is the right solution to this problem, but I started learning linear algebra about a month ago so I wanted to solve the problem using matrixes, until I figured out that numpy was banned and It takes $N^3$ to calculate matrix multiplications. The answer required involves the trace value, and I was stuck on generalizing it.

Comment: Here's the link to the problem I was stuck on: https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/27309

Comment: Maybe you can google-translate the whole page I suppose?

Comment: Interesting. I doubt that my approach at all resembles the intended solution, but I guess it works